# How to create a loop for SELECT function, to keep data updated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using an Oracle database, and every time it updates, the server doesn't understand this update and needs me to drop it for it to update the data.

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use (cors())

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


// Connection details for the Oracle database
const connectionString = 'dbprod';
const user = 'sapiensproducao';
const password = 'fabrica';

// Connect to the database
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    connectionString: connectionString,
    user: user,
    password: password
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');

    // Execute a SQL query
    const query = 'SELECT CODEMP,CODORI,NUMORP,SEQEOQ,DATREA,HORREA,CODPRO,CODDER,QTDRE1,QTDRFG,CODLOT,OBSEOQ from USU_VPROEXT ORDER BY DATREA DESC, HORREA DESC';
    connection.execute(query, [], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Query was successful!');
      console.log()

      // Render the HTML template and pass the query results as a local variable
      app.get('/teste', (req, res) => {
        res.json(result.rows)
      });
    });
  }
);


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

I thought of creating a loop for this SELECT function, but how can I create it?

How can I keep running this select in a loop, to keep the data always updated?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  An endless loop which keeps re-querying the database won't be particularly useful for a web server because it would never be able to *return a response* to the client.

Comment: I have a front end that this SELECT I'm doing is being sent. I need to keep the data always updated on this front, but the node does not recognize the entry of new data in the database, without having to restart the server. I need to keep the data visually updated at all times.

Comment: Have you looked at Oracle's CQN feature? https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/cqn.html

Answer (score 0):

In the structure of your web server, you only ever query the database *once* and then create an endpoint to serve that data.  Instead, create an endpoint which queries the data whenever it's invoked.  Which may look more like this:

```
// define the endpoint
app.get('/teste', (req, res) => {

  // within the endpoint, query the database
  oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    connectionString: connectionString,
    user: user,
    password: password
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      // DON'T DO THIS, return an actual response to the user
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');

    const query = 'SELECT CODEMP,CODORI,NUMORP,SEQEOQ,DATREA,HORREA,CODPRO,CODDER,QTDRE1,QTDRFG,CODLOT,OBSEOQ from USU_VPROEXT ORDER BY DATREA DESC, HORREA DESC';
    connection.execute(query, [], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        // DON'T DO THIS, return an actual response to the user
        return;
      }
      console.log('Query was successful!');
      console.log();

      // return the results to the user
      res.json(result.rows);
    });
  });
});
```

The key difference here is that instead of wrapping the endpoint in the query, you wrap the query in the endpoint.  So every time the endpoint is invoked it re-queries the database.

Please also note the comments for your error handling.  If you just `return;` from the function and never return a response to the client, the client will just hang until it times out.  Return an actual response, which can include error codes, messages, anything you like.  Even just `res.json(false);` would be better than no response at all.